# JTable does not show the result on the first execution

Tags: java, jtable

The code is to add the data to the JTable.

```
            String [] header = new String [] {"No","Customer","Video","Date","Days","Status-Closed"};
            Contract [] contractArray = contractList.toArray(new Contract [contractList.size()]);
            Object [][] datarow = new Object [contractArray.length][6];

            try{
               //Read the objects from file and store in the List
                ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                          new FileInputStream("contractfile"));
                Object o = inputStream.readObject();

                while(o != null){
                    Contract c = (Contract) o;
                    contractList.add(c);
                    o = inputStream.readObject();
                }

            inputStream.close();                

            } catch (EOFException ex) {
                //
            } 

            //Push data to the array
            int no = 0; 
            for(int i = 0; i < contractArray.length; i++){
                no++;
                datarow[i][0] = no;
                datarow[i][1] = contractArray[i].getAccount().getName();
                datarow[i][2] = contractArray[i].getVideo().getName();
                datarow[i][3] = contractArray[i].getDate();
                datarow[i][4] = contractArray[i].getDay();
                datarow[i][5] = contractArray[i].getClosed();
            }

            //set the table model
            TableModel mod = new DefaultTableModel(datarow,header);
            table.setModel(mod);
```

The first time I click the button, the table just show the header, click the second time the data was put into the table. When debugging, the first time the `datarow[][]` has no element, the second time it had all the objects. 
Why, could anyone help me out please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `Contract [] contractArray = contractList.toArray(new Contract [contractList.size()]);` before loading the list from file. So the size() == 0.

After that `datarow = new Object [contractArray.length][6];` but the length is 0

Comment: oh my bad, such a mistake. Thanks so much